# Application closing - How to debug why

Tags: debugging

I have an Application which is working on another computer than mine. The Application is using external databases. I want to run this Application on my computer. But on my computer - when I launch the Application - it's just closing. I want to know why my Application is closing itself.

Can I debug that Application with something which tells me which part of the application is sending the `Close` event?

Like some kind of file checking: server connection checking. :-)
I guess it would be nice to see the assembler code from the moment the application is closing.

How can I get this information?

Comment: Some information about the application itself would be immensely helpful.  I don't think your question is answerable as-is.  We don't even know what OS it runs on.

Comment: Application running on Windows. Probably written in freepascal.